# Как должен работать %n?

Tags: c++, c, language-lawyer

На Хабре [говорится](//habrahabr.ru/company/pvs-studio/blog/137411/):

> Спецификатор "%n" не учитывает количество символов, выведенных с помощью таких спецификаторов, как "%f". Поэтому, перед "%n" поставим один пробел, чтобы записать в isOkPassword значение 1.

Однако, [проверка](//ideone.com/N8lkNs) показывает, что это вовсе не так:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n;

    printf("%f %n\n", 12.0, &n);
    printf("%d", n);

    return 0;
}
```

```
12.000000 
10
```

А как на самом деле должен работать этот код?
Вроде `%n` для того и нужен, чтобы учитывать форматы, ведь иначе в нём не было бы смысла.

Comment: @StateItPrimitive, с убиранием метки [tag:c++] не согласен. `printf` есть в обоих языках.

Comment: С точки зрения вопроса, он _C_-шный, но с точки зрения привлечения внимания, наверное, и правда стоит оставить метку (например, не редко у вопросов по стандарту _java_ ставят метку _android_). Просто я исходил из того, что специалист по C++ вряд ли обязан знать особенности работы определенных _C-шных_ функций/модификаторов... и поэтому вряд ли сразу ответит на вопрос.

Comment: [На cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) пишут: «returns the number of characters written so far by this call to the function», ни о каком игнорировании выведенного текста речь не идёт. Впрочем, я бы не доверял статьям на Хабре.

Comment: @VladD, там речь не об игнорировании пробелов, а об игнорировании вывода по формату `%f` (полагаю, другие форматы тоже подразумеваются). И это ж блог Pvs Studio - анализатора сишного кода - как-то странно, что им не стоит доверять :(

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ага, уже исправил комментарий.

Comment: @Qwertiy: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-hu0-lQORcs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Спецификатор `%n` приводит к записи в аргумент-приемник общего количества символов посланных к этому моменту в выходной поток ("...the number of characters written to the output stream so far by this call to `fprintf`."). Никакого "не учитывания" каких-то спецификаторов формата в нем нет и быть не может.